# How to disable Qt Mainwindow shortcut applies to the modeless dialog

Tags: c++, qt

I have a modeless Qt dialog created, which has some radio buttons among other controls. The parent main window of the dialog has shortcuts enabled for left and right arrow keys.

Now I open the dialog and move to the radio buttons with tab key and try to change the selected radio buttons with left-right arrow keys. Unfortunately, now left-right arrow keys are passed to the parent window and performs the shortcut operation, rather than changing the radio button in the dialog box. This is really a irritating behavior to me.

How can I avoid this behavior? Is it possible to block the parent's shortcuts in the dialog. I prefer a solution that can be applied only in the dialog box code rather than the main window code.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is about event filtering. You should check it

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html

You can override this function and do some stuff. This is an example of course:

```
bool yourDialog::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e){

        if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
          QKeyEvent* keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
          if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Left)
          {
             //do some stuff
             return true;

          }
          else if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Right)
          {
            //do some stuff
            return true;
          }
        }
         return false;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I had already tried this. Problem is I don't get `QEvent::ShortcutOverride` for lef/right arrow keys in the event filter.

Comment: How about this:
if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            QKeyEvent* keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
            if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Up)
            {
                // do some stuff
            }
            else if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Down)
            {
               // do some stuff
            }
        }

Comment: No, even this doesn't work. Actually, when the arrow keys are passed to the parent, I don't get  any of QEvent::ShortcutOverride, QEvent::Shortcut or QEvent::KeyPress !!!

Comment: Did you use installEventFilter(this); function in the constructor of your dialog class or yourDialogClass->installEventFilter(this); ?

Comment: In my dialog's ctor, I have installed event filters for each radio button, like `rb1->installEventFilter(this); rb2->installEventFilter(this)` etc.